# Mysql Multiple SUM query with JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to update a Mysql table based on a SUM query of another table. 
I am getting back  "Unknown column 't2.part_number' in 'on clause'"

Here is my query

```
UPDATE Dream t1 JOIN
   (
    SELECT SUM(`t2`.`Sales_1_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`t2`.`Sales_2_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`t2`.`Sales_3_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`t2`.`Sales_4_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`t2`.`Sales_5_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`t2`.`Sales_6_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`t2`.`Sales_7_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`t2`.`Sales_8_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`t2`.`Sales_9_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`t2`.`Sales_10_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`t2`.`Sales_11_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`t2`.`Sales_12_Month_Prior`) as Total
    FROM saleshistory t2
    WHERE location = '98'
   ) t2
   ON `t1`.`Part_Number` = `t2`.`part_number`
SET `t1`.`ETAUsage` = `t2`.`Total`
```

Comment: You have to include the part_number column in the subquery

Comment: That's because t2 is the alias for the Subquery and on it you don't have the `part_number` either add it on the subquery alongside a group by  or explain better what it should do so we can help.

Comment: The most outer alias is the one valid for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't select a Part_Number  in your subquery for join on condition

so eg: try selecting  (and group by for get the proper sum result)

```
  UPDATE Dream t1 
  JOIN
     (
      SELECT `t2`.`Part_Number`, 
      SUM(`t2`.`Sales_1_Month_Prior`)+
        SUM(`t2`.`Sales_2_Month_Prior`)+
        SUM(`t2`.`Sales_3_Month_Prior`)+
        SUM(`t2`.`Sales_4_Month_Prior`)+
        SUM(`t2`.`Sales_5_Month_Prior`)+
        SUM(`t2`.`Sales_6_Month_Prior`)+
        SUM(`t2`.`Sales_7_Month_Prior`)+
        SUM(`t2`.`Sales_8_Month_Prior`)+
        SUM(`t2`.`Sales_9_Month_Prior`)+
        SUM(`t2`.`Sales_10_Month_Prior`)+
        SUM(`t2`.`Sales_11_Month_Prior`)+
        SUM(`t2`.`Sales_12_Month_Prior`) as Total
      FROM saleshistory t2
      WHERE location = '98'
      group by  `t2`.`Part_Number`
     ) t3
     ON `t1`.`Part_Number` = `t3`.`part_number`
  SET `t1`.`ETAUsage` = `t3`.`Total`
```

Answer (score -1):

In "on clause" t2 is not referring to table "saelshistory" but instead it refers to the temporary table created using the select query on saleshistory.

To be able to refer to part_number, it has to be selected first and then used in group by, this would change the totals but it looks like you need the aggregation by part_number anyway, 
outer table alias t2 should be like

```
SELECT part_number, SUM(....
FROM saleshistory
GROUP BY part_number
```

Comment: That will require a group by clause on the query.

Comment: Yes, I should have added that but was trying to explain the reason for the error reported. Will make sure I add a more complete response next time. Thanks!

Comment: You can fix your answer. Once you do I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score -2):

you can resolve this isue by changing  **as Total** in your sub query by **as part_number**

Comment: This answer is wrong since the user need the part_number field to JOIN with the other table.

Comment: so we can add part_number befor sum

Comment: That you can do, but then you will need add group by clause.

Comment: You can fix your answer. Once you do I will remove my downvote.

Comment: wa can't add field befor group by function (like sum, count, avg....) without adding it in group by it's automatic

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Of course you can add any field before an aggregation function. The SQL Ansi only obligates you to add this same field to the group by clause. The only database that you can use an aggregation function with a field not being in the group by is MySql and as of the newer versions this was fixed. There is no such thing as automatic like you said.